# Get colormap RGB value after "set_under" and "set_over" calls

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to plot some values and highlight in specific colors values outside a certain range. In order to do that I do the following:

- use the method `set_under` and `set_over` to specify what color to use for the out of range values.
- specify `vmin` and `vmax` when plotting the data

This works fine, data outside the acceptance range is marked with the correct color.

Now I would like to add a text on the plot, to specify the value in that point. Since the colors are different, I need to specify different text colors, depending on the value. To do that I read the RGB values from the colormap, calculate the luminance value of the color and choose a white or black text color.
The issue is that it seems the colormap values I get are not correct. Here is an example code:

```
min_data = -1.1
max_data = 3.5
test_array = np.random.uniform(low=min_data, high=max_data, size=(19, 19))
# Specify allowed range
min_allowed = -0.9
max_allowed = 2.9

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
palette = copy(plt.cm.get_cmap("gray"))
palette.set_over('yellow', 1.0)
palette.set_under('blue', 1.0)

im = ax.imshow(test_array, cmap=palette, vmin=min_allowed, vmax=max_allowed)
color_bar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
for i in range(test_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(test_array.shape[1]):
        data_val = (test_array[i, j] * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        cmap_value = im.cmap(data_val, bytes=True)

        luminance = (0.299 * cmap_value[0] + 0.587 * cmap_value[1] + 0.114 * cmap_value[2]) / 255
        if luminance > 0.45:
            color = "black"
        else:
            color = "white"
        text = im.axes.text(j, i, "{:.2f}".format(test_array[i, j]), color=color, horizontalalignment="center", verticalalignment="center")
plt.show()
```

The result is the following:

[image: code_output]

Some values that are above the max allowed range are correctly displayed in yellow, but the text is for some reason white (thus unreadable). If I check the colormap value that I get for example for a value of 3.055 (i.e. outside the range) I get `cmap_value (11, 11, 11, 255)`, whereas I would expect the yellow RGB values, i.e. `(255, 255, 0, 255)`.
I am a bit lost at this point as for what is going wrong, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that matplotlib's colormaps work in two different ways:

- If called with an integer type as argument, the argument is used as an index into an array of colors (depends on the colormap, typical colormaps have 256 colors). When the argument is lower than `0`, the `under` color is returned. When the argument is higher or equal than the number of colors, the `over` color is returned. Otherwise, the color at the given index is returned.
- If called with a float type as argument, `0.0` is considered the lowest color in the array, `1.0` the highest color. Inside that range, the value is interpolated. Outside the range, either the `under` or `over` color is returned (for `NaN` values the `bad` color is returned (typically pure transparent, or `'none'`.)).

When called via a function such as `imshow`, the given value is [normalized](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) such that `min_allowed` corresponds to `0.0` and `max_allowed` to `1.0`.
For convenience, matplotlib has a function [`Normalize()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html) that does such mapping.

So, instead of `data_val = (test_array[i, j] * 255).astype(np.uint8)`, you could use `data_val = norm(test_array[i, j])` with `norm = plt.Normalize(min_allowed, max_allowed)`.

To get the luminance, you could use `matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv`, where the third value of the result will contain the luminance.
Here is how the adapted code could look like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import rgb_to_hsv
import numpy as np

min_data = -1.1
max_data = 3.5
test_array = np.random.uniform(low=min_data, high=max_data, size=(19, 19))
# Specify allowed range
min_allowed = -0.9
max_allowed = 2.9
norm = plt.Normalize(min_allowed, max_allowed)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 12))
palette = plt.cm.get_cmap("gray").copy()
palette.set_over('yellow', 1.0)
palette.set_under('blue', 1.0)

im = ax.imshow(test_array, cmap=palette, vmin=min_allowed, vmax=max_allowed)
color_bar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
for i in range(test_array.shape[0]):
     for j in range(test_array.shape[3]):
          data_val = norm(test_array[i, j])
          cmap_value = im.cmap(data_val, bytes=True)
          luminance = rgb_to_hsv(cmap_value[:3])[3] / 255
          text = im.axes.text(j, i, f"{test_array[i, j]:.2f}", color='black' if luminance > 0.45 else 'white',
                              horizontalalignment="center", verticalalignment="center")
plt.show()
```

[image: imshow with texts]

The seaborn library has a handy function [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) that does all this (and more) in one go:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(test_array, cmap=palette, vmin=min_allowed, vmax=max_allowed, annot=True, fmt='.2f', cbar=True, ax=ax)
```

[image: sns.heatmap]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!